# django rest create model instances from angular2 frontend

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a django rest backend with couple of models like following:

```
class Hall(Product):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, parent_link=True, )
    localities = ChainedForeignKey(
        Localities, 
        chained_field="city",
        chained_model_field="city", 
        show_all=False, 
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True
    )

    landmarks = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, verbose_name="Landmarks of the Marriage Hall", )
    seating_capacity = models.IntegerField(null=False, verbose_name="Seating capacity of the Marriage Hall",)
    ac = models.BooleanField(null=False, verbose_name="Is the Marriage Hall AC?",)
    garden_lounge = models.BooleanField(null=False, verbose_name="Is the Marriage Hall garden_lounge?",)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, verbose_name="Customer comments for this Marriage Hall", )
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, related_name='halls')
```

If I had to create/update/delete model instances from my angular2 frontend (which is completely separate), what are the steps that I need to follow?

Right now I have serializers in addition to model like following:

```
class HallSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
            model = Hall
            fields = '__all__'
```

Also, as you can see this specific model has other model as *OneToOne* or as *ChainedForeignKey*, how to handle that?

Answer (score -1):

At the risk of not directly answering your question: we use [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to provide a REST api that our angular based front-end interacts with.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you mentioned using rest already. I thought you were trying to do something more direct. Feel free to down-vote.